# Where to find driver to wireless adapter?

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, wireless-adapter

My laptop has Broadcom 802.11g Network Adapter.

I was wondering where to find its driver? I searched on the internet but found some faked website, and on the Broadcom website I couldn't find a page for its driver.

Comment: What is your laptop make and model number? Often you will have to look for drivers on the laptop manufacturer's site.

Comment: Oftentimes there is a part number for the adapter too.

Comment: Unknown Device Identifier: http://www.zhangduo.com/udi.html - might help you find the driver you need, you'll be able to get specific information about chipset and all from that program

Comment: @Rolnik: What is the part number of an adapter? how to get it?

Comment: Thanks, MaQleod! I saw via DUI, the chip for the adapter is bcm 4309 802 11a/b/g. Is that called part number or something else? Is it all the information needed to find the driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim, you are on the right track.  Once you locate the PCI vendor ID and device ID (PCI/VEN_14E4&DEV_4309), a quick trip to pcidatabase.com often reveals more information about the precise hardware.

```
Chip Number:    BCM4309
Chip Description:   802.11a/b/g Wireless LAN Controller
Notes:  Installed in Latitude D500, D600, Inspiron 8500 [called TrueMobile 1400], Precision M60, Dell Latitu
```

Edit: OOPS just saw your comment that you have a 4309, making it a BCM4309.  Those were installed by Dell.  It is suggested to go through the Dell support site, entering the appropriate model number of the system, and locate the Wireless drivers download once there.

Comment: Get the Dell driver.

Comment: Thanks! But my laptop is Acer Aspire 5000 not Dell.

Comment: Tried Acer support driver download?  http://www.acer.com, Service & Support, Notebooks, Aspire, Aspire 5000, then in drivers list that appears, the Broadcom Wireless driver is at the bottom of list.

Answer (score 1):

I am amazed that you couldn't find it on Broadcom. Generally, all Broadcom Ethernet drivers should be available from the manufacturer here: http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/downloaddrivers.php. Maybe you downloaded a driver for the wrong adapter model?

I don't know if there is a way to determine the correct model using XP when the driver is not installed  (when it is installed, running ipconfig in command line lists all NICs with their model). When I reinstalled my laptop (I also have a Broadcom NIC) I had the same problem as you. I booted from an Ubuntu LiveCD. Typing lspci in the terminal lists the way all devices identify themselves to the OS. I had there a line which states `09:00. Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5755M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)`. So I just downloaded the driver for the NetXtreme 5755 chipset from the page I linked above.

If this solution doesn't work for you, where is the problem exactly? Does lspci list a Broadcom model not found on their driver page? If yes, I suggest that you call their tech support, because that would be a big mistake on their part.

Comment: Thanks! But I think Ethernet NIC and wireless NIC are different, so your link is not for wireless NIC. Moreover, For more information, my adapter chip is bcm 4309 802 11a/b/g, and the detail about the adapter is PCI\VEN_14E4&DEV_4318&.... Maybe I am stupid, but I can't find it on the Broadcom website. What kind of information is enough for finding its driver, and where can I find its driver?

Answer (score 1):

Try to look here: http://lotofdrivers.com/driver/64758_DellInspiron8500BroadcomEthernetDriver.htm. This page to download Dell Inspiron 8500 Broadcom Ethernet Driver.